# Cobol Copybook to Collibra : Common practice/architecture

Tags: metadata, mainframe, copybook, collibra

What is the common practice for importing Copybook Metadata to Collibra ?
I'm trying to import Copybook schema into Collibra DGC.

I am planning to follow these mapping structure :

```
Copybook Asset
  |
  |__ Field Assest
  |
  |__ Field Assest
  | |
  | |__ Field Assest
  | |
  | |__ Field Assest
  |
  |__ Field Assest
```

But the problem is in Collibra I can't find any asset properties (for Asset Type Field) to store Field Attributes I'm receiving from Copybook Schema.

So, can anyone who have experiences in these kinds of integration scenario suggest any better alternatives or guidance ?

I'm using Mule Framework for developing the integration flow.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I feel like this a question for the Collibra support people have you contacted them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using the OOTB Data Attribute (or Data Element) asset types for those Field Attribute and see if those asset properties (or Attribute Types) match with your goals. Adding an Asset Type "Field Attribute" is fine as well. If you are missing any asset types or attributetypes in the OOTB model simply add them to the metamodel in Settings. See https://compass.collibra.com/display/DGC50/Setting+up+your+own+data+governance+operating+model

I would also ask the Collibra community at https://community.collibra.com/forums/forum/product-questions-answers/

Kind regards,
Stan